# In Putty, how do you locate where an error is based on the char position?

Tags: sql, netezza

I received the following error, which is based off  of my code (attached below) in Netezza .

```
 ^ found "WHERE" (at char 543) expecting an identifier found a keyword
```

But how I find where in the code this is located at? Do I  need to divide 543 by the amount of characters per line ?

the code is shown below :

```
DELETE FROM TDM_FEE_DISCOUNT_FACT;;

----------------------------------------------------------------------------
-- INSERT INTO TDM TABLE ---
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
INSERT INTO FEE_DISCOUNT_FACT 
(   
            FEE_DISCNT_F_DK ,
            HLTH_PLN_GRP_DK,
            HLTH_PLN_SPSR_DK,
            PLN_MBR_DK,
            COV_PRD_STRT_DT,
            COV_PRD_END_DT,
            BIL_DUE_DT,
            FEE_AMT,
            DISCNT_AMT,
            BIL_ID,
            SS_CD,
            TNT_CD,
            INSRT_DT,
            UPDT_DT,
            CREAT_RUN_CYC_EXEC_SK,
            LST_UPDT_RUN_CYC_EXEC_SK,
            REC_PRCS_TYP_CD,
            ROW_EFF_STRT_DT,
            ROW_EFF_END_DT,
            CUR_ROW_IND

)
WITH LAST_RUN_DATE(DT) AS
(
   SELECT NVL(LAST_RUN, TO_DATE('01/01/1900', 'MM/DD/YYYY'))
   FROM (
      SELECT MAX(NVL(TCT.MANIFEST_COMPLETED_TS, TO_DATE('01/01/1900', 'MM/DD/YYYY'))) LAST_RUN
      FROM :DB_XREF..TGT_CONTROL_TBL TCT
      WHERE MANIFEST = 'F_FEE_DISCOUNT'
   ) T
)
,  
--Need to modify the following section  , on line 66 of FEE_DISCOUNT_FACT
DRIVER AS 
(

    select 
     PM.HLTH_PLN_GRP_NBR||'|'||SBFD.SS_CD AS HLTH_PLN_GRP_BK
    ,PM.HLTH_PLN_GRP_NBR AS SPSR_ID
    ,PM.PLN_MBR_SK
      --COV_PRD_STRT_DT
      --COV_PRD_END_DT

    ,SBFD.BIL_DUE_DT AS BIL_DUE_DT
    ,NVL(SBFD.FEE_AMT,0) AS FEE_AMT
    ,NVL(SBFD.DISCNT_AMT,0) AS DISCNT_AMT
    ,SBFD.BIL_ID 
    ,SBFD.SS_CD
    ,SBFD.FEE_DISCNT_CREAT_DT_TM
    from MBRBOR_TGT_D4..SUBSCRIBER_BILLING_FEE_DISCOUNT SBFD
    LEFT OUTER JOIN MBRBOR_TGT_D4..PLAN_MEMBER PM 
           ON  PM.SBSCR_SK = SBFD.SBSCR_SK 
           AND PM.CUR_ROW_IND = 'Y'
           AND PM.REC_PRCS_TYP_CD <> 'D'
           AND PM.SBSCR_DPND_RLNSP_TYP_CD_SK IN (SELECT CD_MAP_SK FROM REFBOR_TGT_D4..CODEMAP
                                                                       WHERE  CONFOR_CD = 'SUB')

)

 /* IN the code, only need to join to the dimensions .. FACT DK's are the sequence */
SELECT NEXT VALUE FOR FEE_DISCOUNT_F_SEQ                    AS FEE_DISCNT_F_DK,
    NVL(HPGD.HLTH_PLN_GRP_DK,-9)                            AS HLTH_PLN_GRP_DK,
    NVL(HPGD.HLTH_PLN_SPSR_DK,-9)                           AS HLTH_PLN_SPSR_DK,
    PM.PLN_MBR_SK                                           AS PLN_MBR_DK,
    NVL(??.COV_PRD_STRT_DT,-9)                              AS COV_PRD_STRT_DT,
    NVL(??.COV_PRD_END_DT,-9)                               AS COV_PRD_END_DT,
    NVL(BIL_DUE_DT,0)                                       AS BIL_DUE_DT,
    NVL(FEE_AMT,  0)                                        AS FEE_AMT,
    NVL(DISCNT_AMT, 0)                                      AS DISCNT_AMT,
    NVL(BIL_ID,-9)                                          AS BIL_ID,
    DR.SS_CD                                                AS SS_CD,
    'BSC'                                                   AS TNT_CD,
    NOW()                                                   AS INSRT_DT,
    NOW()                                                   AS UPDT_DT,
    NVL(SBFD.CREAT_RUN_CYC_EXEC_SK,-9)                      AS CREAT_RUN_CYC_EXEC_SK,
    NVL(SBFD.LST_UPDT_RUN_CYC_EXEC_SK,-9)                   AS LST_UPDT_RUN_CYC_EXEC_SK,
    NVL(SBFD.REC_PRCS_TYP_CD,0)                             AS REC_PRCS_TYP_CD,
    NVL(SBFD.ROW_EFF_STRT_DT,0)                                 AS ROW_EFF_STRT_DT,
    NVL(SBFD.ROW_EFF_END_DT,0)                                  AS ROW_EFF_END_DT,
    NVL(SBFD.CUR_ROW_IND,0)                                 AS CUR_ROW_IND   --FEE_DISCNT_CREAT_DT_TM

FROM DRIVER DR
LEFT OUTER JOIN :DB_TGT..HEALTH_PLAN_GROUP_DIMENSION HPGD ON DR.HLTH_PLN_GRP_BK = HPGD.HLTH_PLN_GRP_BK
AND FEE_DISCNT_CREAT_DT_TM BETWEEN HPGD.ROW_EFF_STRT_DT AND HPGD.ROW_EFF_END_DT
LEFT OUTER JOIN :DB_TGT..HEALTH_PLAN_SPONSOR_DIMENSION HPSD ON DR.SPSR_ID = HPSD.SPSR_ID
AND FEE_DISCNT_CREAT_DT_TM BETWEEN HPSD.ROW_EFF_STRT_DT AND HPSD.ROW_EFF_END_DT --DONE
--some of the joins will have different conditions .  like for SS_CD it will be different
LEFT OUTER JOIN :DB_TGT..PLAN_MEMBER_DIMENSION PMD ON DR.PLN_MBR_SK = PMD.PLN_MBR_SK
AND FEE_DISCNT_CREAT_DT_TM BETWEEN PMD.ROW_EFF_STRT_DT AND PMD.ROW_EFF_END_DT


--LEFT OUTER JOIN   

LEFT OUTER JOIN 
(SELECT SBSCR.PLN_MBR_DK AS SBSCR_DK, PM.*
    FROM :DB_TGT..PLAN_MEMBER_DIMENSION PM 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN 
        (SELECT PM.PLN_MBR_DK, PM.PLN_MBR_SK, PM.SBSCR_SK, PM.CUR_ROW_IND, PM.ROW_EFF_STRT_DT, PM.ROW_EFF_END_DT FROM 
         :DB_TGT..PLAN_MEMBER_DIMENSION PM WHERE PLN_MBR_SK = SBSCR_SK) SBSCR
    ON PM.SBSCR_SK = SBSCR.SBSCR_SK AND (PM.ROW_EFF_END_DT -1) BETWEEN 
    SBSCR.ROW_EFF_STRT_DT AND SBSCR.ROW_EFF_END_DT) PMD 
    ON DR.PLN_MBR_SK = PMD.PLN_MBR_SK
    AND DR.CAPITN_ERN_FROM_DT BETWEEN PMD.ROW_EFF_STRT_DT AND PMD.ROW_EFF_END_DT
```

Thanks

Comment: can you please show your code so we could analyse?

Comment: @FerdinandGaspar  - done, thx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since vi is the editor used for the queries (if you're in nzsql) - you can navigate 543 characters from the start by typing in `0543l` in the editor - this will take you the start, then 543 steps to the "right". This should bring you to the area of the sql where the problem is.